# Amazon web service. How to authenticate?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am going to write a small program that query Amazon web service for book information.

Given some sample I found online, I wrote;

```
namespace TestWCF
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter keyword: ");
            var line = Console.ReadLine();
            if (line == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            using (var svc = new AmazonSearchPortClient())
            {
                var keywordReq = new KeywordRequest
                                     {
                                         locale = "us",
                                         type = "lite",
                                         sort = "reviewrank",
                                         mode = "books",
                                         keyword = line,
                                         tag = "associate-id",
                                         devtag = "????????????"
                                     };

                var productInfo = svc.KeywordSearchRequest(keywordReq);
                foreach(var detail in productInfo.Details)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(detail.ProductName);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This does not work as it returns authenticate failure at the line;

```
            var productInfo = svc.KeywordSearchRequest(keywordReq);
```

I am not sure what information I should put into the tag and devtag fields. Someone says I should put associate ID but what I shall put into the devtag?

Many thanks,

Regards.
}

Comment: I am also looking for the answer.